# van der Vaart Asymptotic Statistics, page 38, why does $e_\theta'=\operatorname{Cov}_{\theta}t(X)$?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, expected-value, covariance, exponential-family

On Page 38 of van der Vaart's Asymptotic Statistics (near the bottom of the page), it says

> By differentiating $E_\theta t(X)$ under the expectation sign (which is justified by the lemma), we see that its derivative matrices are given by $e'_\theta=\operatorname{Cov}_\theta t(X)$.

I'm wondering why this is true. A detailed proof or explanation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me provide some ingredients so that you may yourself work this out formally:

Let $\mathbf N$ be the natural parameter space. Let $\nu$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure. Define $\lambda(\boldsymbol{\theta}) :=\int \exp(\mathbf T\cdot\boldsymbol{\theta})~\mathrm d\nu $ and $\psi(\boldsymbol{\theta}):= \ln \lambda(\boldsymbol{\theta}). $

$\bullet$ For any $\boldsymbol{\theta}_0 \in \operatorname{int}(\mathbf N),$ it can be shown that $\boldsymbol\nabla \lambda(\boldsymbol{\theta}) = \int \mathbf T\exp(\mathbf T\cdot\boldsymbol{\theta})~\mathrm d\nu. $ Specifically, show that the absolute value of $d(\mathbf T, \boldsymbol\theta):= \frac{\exp(\boldsymbol\theta\cdot \mathbf T)- \exp(\boldsymbol\theta_0\cdot \mathbf T)- (\boldsymbol\theta-\boldsymbol\theta_0)\cdot \boldsymbol\nabla \lambda(\boldsymbol{\theta_0})}{\Vert\boldsymbol\theta-\boldsymbol\theta_0\Vert} $ vanishes as $\boldsymbol\theta\to\boldsymbol\theta_0.$ Then use DCT.

$\bullet$ From the above relation,  $\boldsymbol\nabla \exp(\psi(\boldsymbol{\theta})) =\lambda(\boldsymbol{\theta})\boldsymbol\nabla \psi(\boldsymbol{\theta}) =  \int \mathbf T\exp(\mathbf T\cdot\boldsymbol{\theta})~\mathrm d\nu.$ Whence $\mathbb E_\boldsymbol\theta(\mathbf T) =  \boldsymbol\nabla \psi(\boldsymbol{\theta}) .$

$\bullet$ You can then show by routine vectorial manipulation that $\operatorname{Cov}_\boldsymbol\theta (\mathbf T) = \boldsymbol\nabla '\boldsymbol\nabla \psi(\boldsymbol{\theta}) .$  You can also verify that calculating $\frac{\partial^2 \psi(\boldsymbol\theta)}{\partial\boldsymbol\theta\partial\boldsymbol\theta'}$ which would be easier.

$\bullet$ Finally one can always resort to mgf, which in this case would be $\mathrm M_\mathbf T(\mathbf s) = \exp(\psi(\boldsymbol\theta+ \mathbf s) - \psi(\boldsymbol\theta)).$ From this, it is easy to check $\frac{\partial \psi(\boldsymbol\theta)}{\partial \theta_i} = \mathbb E_\boldsymbol\theta(T_i)$ and $\frac{\partial^2 \psi(\boldsymbol\theta)}{\partial \theta_i\partial\theta_j} = \operatorname{Cov}_\boldsymbol\theta(T_i,T_j).$

---

### References

$\bullet$ Fundamentals of Statistical Exponential Families: With Applications in Statistical Decision Theory, *Lawrence D. Brown,* IMS, $1986, $ Theorem $2.2, $ pp. $34-35.$

$\bullet$ Theory of Statistical Inference, *Anthony Almudevar,* Taylor & Francis, $2022, $ Theorem $3.13, $ p. $75.$

Comment: Thank you very much! This is very helpful!

Comment: @ExcitedSnail I would be happy to expand any pointer if you wish. But first give yourself a try.